# PHP D3 combination for visualizing data

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I am trying to visualize the data from the currencylayer API.
I am trying to use this as an example: http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=xxxxxxxxxxx&format=1", true));

$keys_array = array();
$values_array = array();
$arra = array();
foreach($response->quotes as $key => $value) {
//    echo "$key is at $value\n";
//      array_push($keys_array, substr($key,3));
//    array_push($values_array,$value);

    array_push($arra,{"letter":substr($key,3),"frequency":$value});
}
print_r($arra);
?>
```

I am trying to achieve the data in the form of:

```
[
  {letter: "A", frequency: .08167},
  {letter: "B", frequency: .01492},
  {letter: "C", frequency: .02780},
  {letter: "D", frequency: .04253},
  {letter: "E", frequency: .12702},
  {letter: "F", frequency: .02288},
  {letter: "G", frequency: .02022},
  {letter: "H", frequency: .06094},
  {letter: "I", frequency: .06973},
  {letter: "J", frequency: .00153},
  {letter: "K", frequency: .00747},
  {letter: "L", frequency: .04025},
  {letter: "M", frequency: .02517},
  {letter: "N", frequency: .06749},
  {letter: "O", frequency: .07507},
  {letter: "P", frequency: .01929},
  {letter: "Q", frequency: .00098},
  {letter: "R", frequency: .05987},
  {letter: "S", frequency: .06333},
  {letter: "T", frequency: .09056},
  {letter: "U", frequency: .02758},
  {letter: "V", frequency: .01037},
  {letter: "W", frequency: .02465},
  {letter: "X", frequency: .00150},
  {letter: "Y", frequency: .01971},
  {letter: "Z", frequency: .00074}
]
```

If I get the values in the above format then I can assign the php variable to the `d3 data`variable and visualize accordingly.

The above php code is giving error as follows:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in file.php on line 18
```

Kindly, help me in fixing the error and assignment of the variable to the d3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing JSON with PHP, JSON is an javascript object anotation and it won't work in php. You need to use arrays in php and then encode them as json.

```
<?php
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://apilayer.net/api/live?access_key=xxxxxxxxxxx&format=1", true));

$keys_array = array();
$values_array = array();
$arra = array();
foreach($response->quotes as $key => $value) {
//    echo "$key is at $value\n";
//      array_push($keys_array, substr($key,3));
//    array_push($values_array,$value);

    $arra[] = [
        "letter" => substr($key,3),
        "frequency" => $value
    ];
}
print_r($arra);

// echo json_encode($arra); // to convert the array to json 
?>
```

Comment: Wow! this worked... BUt is it possible to assign the variable to the javascript d3?

Comment: After encoding will it be possible to use it in the javascript.. please enlighten

Comment: yes, see [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Comment: I just wanted to assign the values as it is. Hence converted the array to json and then tried to assign to javascript variable: `var data = <?php echo $jsonvalues ?>;` But not working. :(

Answer (score 1):

Just change your line from

```
array_push($arra,{"letter":substr($key,3),"frequency":$value});
```

to

```
array_push($arra,array("letter"=>substr($key,3),"frequency"$value));
```

Since i dont have the conent of that file so can't predict wether it can fix the issue.